# React-Native: Element type is invalid

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have problem with nativebase Footer
I have Container and if I include MyFooter, it give me this error: 
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

```
// main.js
import MyFooter from './MyFooter';
...
<Container>
    <MyHeader title="Оплаты" />
    <Content></Content>
    <MyFooter />
  </Container>
```

And Footer component

```
// MyFooter.js
const MyFooter = props => {
  return (
    <Footer>
      <FooterTab>
        <Button vertical active>
          <Text>Info</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button vertical >
            <Text>Remove</Text>
        </Button>
      </FooterTab>
    </Footer>
  );
}
export default MyFooter;
```

But if I change render method of MyFooter like this:

```
// MyFooter.js
return (
  <View>
    <Text>
      Test
    </Text>
  </View>
)
```

So problem not in export/import, because with another render in MyFooter all work perfectly.
Can anybody help with this, please?

**Answer** - import { Text, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon } from 'react-native'; ('react-native' instead 'native-base')

Comment: have you export your `MyFooter` component

Comment: Yes, if I change render method of MyFooter all work perfect. (Add line of export to question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pasted your code exactly as is, then you're missing your closing brace after your return statement in MyFooter.js

Comment: no, closing brace does not fit due to the limitation in the amount of code in the question, sorry about this.

Comment: Ok, and in MyFooter.js you're importing all the elements from Nativebase, and not React-Native?  Button, Text, etc.

Comment: @NikitaR.does it work if you wrap Footer in a View?  So <View><Footer>...</Footer></View>  ?

Comment: import { Text, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon } from 'react-native';
That`s where there was an error, what a shame..

Comment: @NikitaR. Yeah that's what I was wondering with my first comment here, I believe I've ran into that issue before when converting existing views to use NativeBase.  It's a very frustrating issue to track down.  Glad you found it!

Answer (score 2):

Is this your `MyFooter` component try to export your component first `export default MyFooter` like these following:

```
const MyFooter = () => (   
  <Footer>
    <FooterTab>
      <Button vertical active>
        <Icon name="information" />
        <Text>Инфо</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button vertical >
        <Icon name="add" />
        <Text>Оплаты</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button vertical >
        <Icon name="remove" />
        <Text>Снятия</Text>
      </Button>
    </FooterTab>
  </Footer>
);

export default MyFooter;
```

Comment: export is exists, so problem not in import/export, add line of export in question, sorry, must do it at first.

Comment: is this solve your problem ? let me know if not solve yet try to change you component declaration from this `const MyFooter = props =>` to `const MyFooter = () =>`

Comment: Not, this is not solve problem, export was exist before. If problem was in export, then changes in MyHeader render gave the same error.

Comment: have you try to change the render method to const `MyFooter = () => ( your component )`